# POST method without refreshing page. Spring MVC. JAVA. JSP

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

How to do that when submiting my form at JSP page it will not reload? Here is user sending message and AJAX script (its in my jsp) get back all messages for user. But when i send message (do POST method) it refreshing my page that take some time to loading all messages with AJAX.
Help pls!!!
This is my JSP page

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    prefix="security"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Сообщения | Haine and Vold</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<c:url value="/resources/faviicon/iconHV.ico"/>" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/CSS/styles.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/CSS/tableMessFixedHeader.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/Angular/angular.min.js"/>"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Haine and Vold</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><spring:message
                                code="label.menuprofile" /><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/haine/user"><spring:message
                                        code="label.menuprofile" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/haine/user/updateinfo"><spring:message
                                        code="label.menusettinginfo" /></a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="/haine/user/messages"><spring:message
                                code="label.menumessages" /> (${allUserMess})</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/haine/user/search"><spring:message
                                code="label.menusearch" /></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><spring:message
                                code="label.menuinformation" /><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/haine/user/rules"><spring:message
                                        code="label.menurules" /></a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="/haine/user/feedback"><spring:message
                                        code="label.menusendfeedback" /></a></li>
                        </ul></li>

                    <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><spring:message
                                    code="label.menuadministration" /><span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="/haine/admin"><spring:message
                                            code="label.menuadminpanel" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/haine/admin/feedbacklist"><spring:message
                                            code="label.menufeedbacks" />(${countOfFeedbacks})</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/haine/admin/newusers"><spring:message
                                            code="label.newusers" />(${countOfNewUsers})</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                    </security:authorize>

                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="?locale=ru"><img
                            src="<c:url value="/resources/languageicons/rus.png"/>"
                            alt="Russian Language" title="Сменить язык интерфейса на русский"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="?locale=en"><img
                            src="<c:url value="/resources/languageicons/usa.png"/>"
                            alt="USA Language" title="Change interface language to american"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="${logoutUrl}"
                    method="post">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                        <spring:message code="label.logoutbutton" />
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        value="${_csrf.token}" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive logo" src="/haine/resources/logo.jpg">
</div>
<br>
<div class="scrollTableMessages" id="mess">
</div>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="message"
                        accept-charset="utf-8" ng-app="vandh" ng-controller="validateCtrl"
                        name="messageForm" novalidation="true">

<form:textarea path="text" class="form-control" rows="1" 
                            id="message" ng-model="message" required="true"></form:textarea>
                        <div style="color: black"
                            ng-show="messageForm.message.$dirty && messageForm.message.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="messageForm.message.$error.required"><spring:message
                                code="label.entermessage" /></span>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><spring:message
                                code="label.sendmessage"/></button>
                        </div>

</form:form>

<script>
        var app = angular.module('vandh', []);
        app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = '';
        });
    </script>
</body>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

    </script>


<script>
var oldC = 0, newC = -1;
    function getMessages() {
        $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/haine/user/countofmess/${iddialog}',
        success : function(rs) 
        {
            newC = rs;
            if(oldC != newC)
            {
                $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : '/haine/user/mess/${iddialog}',
                success : function(r) 
                {
                    $('#mess').html(r);
                    document.getElementById("mess").scrollTop = 9999;
                    console.log(r);

                },
                error : function(r) {
                    alert(r);
                }
                });
                oldC = newC;
            }
        },
        error : function(rs) {
            alert(rs);
        }
        });
    }
    setInterval(getMessages, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```

And this is my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/messages/{iddialog}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String messages(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message, @RequestParam(value = "text") String text,
            @PathVariable(value = "iddialog") int iddialog, Model model, Principal principal) {
        if(checkingMessage(text)!=true)
        {
        sendMessage(iddialog, text, principal.getName());

        System.out.println("message sent!");
            return "messagesWithUser";
        }
        else
        {
            return "redirect:/user/messages";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Spring version.
if you are using Spring 3, JQuery you could do someting like this:

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!doctype html>
<html  lang="es" >
<head></head>
<body>    
    Your Name: <input type='text' id='name'>
    <button id='send-button'>Send</button>
    <div id='state-bar'></div>

    <script>
     window.onload=function() {
                var stateBar=$("#state-bar");
                var name=$("#name");
                var sendButton=$("#send-button");

                sendButton.click(function( event ) {
                    var parameters={
                        name: name.val()
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        type:  'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data:  JSON.stringify(parameters), 
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "myPage.htm",
                        success:  function (data) {
                            stateBar.html(data.response);
                        }, error: function(data){
                            stateBar.html("Server Error.");
                        }
                    });
                });
     }
    </script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.company.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/testPage.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testPage(){
        return "testPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/myPage.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public MyPageResponse myPage(@RequestBody MyPageModel myPageModel){
        MyPageResponse res= new MyPageResponse();
        res.setResponse("Your name is : "+myPageModel.getName());
        return res;
    }

}
```

**Input VO**

```
package com.company.controllers;

public class MyPageModel {
   private String name="";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Output VO**

```
package com.company.controllers;

public class MyPageResponse {
    private String response="";

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />


    <mvc:interceptors>
     <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
     <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
     <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
     <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
     <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
     </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: thanx for an answer, but it's didn't help!

Comment: Did you try the example? do you have some error in the log file? May be need some libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the default action for a submit button is sending the request as a normal request (not ajax).

You have to change your form to:

```
 <form onsubmit="return false;"  class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="${logoutUrl}"
                    method="post">
                    <button onclick="function_ajax_to_send_form()" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                        <spring:message code="label.logoutbutton" />
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        value="${_csrf.token}" />
                </form>
```